# Looking for a well-designed server reporting and analytics tool

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring

I'm looking for a hosted reporting and analytics tool for our REST api and website. Basically, I'd like something designed from the ground up with simplicity in mind.

We would like to

- Have some way to tell the tool when an event occurs
- Have some way to report statistics over time
- Be able to create simple custom reports on that data over time

One concrete example: We'd like to be able to report the response time of each url in our api, and be able to sort those by response time, so we can identify bottlenecks.

Are there are new tools out there that are well-designed, and easy to jump in to? I'm aware of many current solutions, but most seem to be focused on the enterprise, and they are almost always overkill.

Comment: To clarify: I'm looking for something like Flurry or Google Analytics, but for servers. Not only should it provide common metrics, like CPU usage, but also allow for custom events (like how Google Analytics tracks your top pages, or flurry will let you send custom events and graph stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zabbix](http://zabbix.com) may be one possiblity for you as it can do what you need but you have to host this yourself on the same server or another, its definitely not simple to jump into first time but can work well

[bijk](http://bijk.com/?r=wsxsn) could be made to work with your required functionality as well and is hosted, its reasonably simple to get going but there are some quirks and i dont think you will be able to get sorting of response times

[pingdom](http://pingdom.com) can do server response times of your api and alert for downtime issues however it cant do the server graphing that you want

Answer (score 0):

Go with zabbix. You can rent a cheap dedicated server where you can install it. This way you can also monitor from outside the service availability.

You will find many useful scripts who will help you to monitor all kind of events up to the hardware (e.g. SNMP).

Answer (score 0):

LogicMonitor provide hosted monitoring for a price. Easy to setup and use.

http://www.logicmonitor.com/

Zabbix is probably the most flexible option but you won't find it hosted anywhere and it's not as easy to get into as other tools like Spiceworks and OpsManager.